# Perform action on clicking a tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show tooltip when a div is hover on. By clicking that tooltip, I need to execute some action. This similar to Gmail's compose mail. It shows the formatting options on clicking A icon.

Comment: could you please give a link to refer?

Comment: Yes you can do that.. Just give fiddle link so that we can edit it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cXmba/1/ Here on hover over any cell it should show tooltip. On clicking the tooltip, the current cell should be colored to green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty good solution here:

http://abbysdoor.com/clickable-tooltips-in-jquery-ui/

[Fiddle from that link](http://jsfiddle.net/abbylangner/XHb4Z/)

```
function setClickableTooltip(target, content){
$( target ).tooltip({
    show: null, // show immediately 
    position: { my: "left bottom", at: "right center" },
    content: content, //from params
    hide: { effect: "" }, //fadeOut
    close: function(event, ui){
        ui.tooltip.hover(
            function () {
                $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1); 
            },
            function () {
                $(this).fadeOut("400", function(){
                    $(this).remove(); 
                })
            }
        );
    }  
});
```

}

Comment: The thing is I am working in backbone js. So how can I use this?